# How to customize date format?

Tags: datetime, latex

I want to customize the date format (in the article document class) in such a way, that when I write `\today` (or similar), then the result is: '10. december 2023'. The months should be spelled in Danish and in lower case. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please add a [mre] so we can see which class you use and if you use any language packages like babel or polyglossia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, easily, without touching the `article` class file. Using the package [`babel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) with option `danish` also changes the format of the date: the following code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text.
\end{document}
```

gives this output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Also, you can read section 9.2 of the [`article` class manual](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf), saying something more about months in the `date` macro.

---

### Addendum

The command `\today{}`, better followed by braces for the sake of better spacing, also works within a .tex file recalled by the command `\input` in the main .tex file.

##### Main tex file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{content.tex}

\end{document}
```

##### content.tex file:

```latex
Text, \today{} text.
```

The output is the following:

[image: output modified]

Comment: I need to use the \today-command after \begin{document} (in connection with a preface in an \input-file) and then the provided code doesn't work. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: @PeterJensen I have edited my answer :) If you need more help, please post your code!